# Updating a column in a Pandas DataFrame based on a condition of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm interested in adding a text tag to a new column in a Pandas dataframe.  The following example works but I get the copy warning and I don't fully understand if I should ignore it in this case.

The DataFrame simply has either a character or is an empty string:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df=pd.DataFrame({('A'):['x','','x',''], ('B'):['x','x','','']})

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   A  B
0  x  x
1     x
2  x
3
```

Create a new column called 'msg'

```
In [4]: df['msg'] = ''

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
   A  B msg
0  x  x
1     x
2  x
3
```

Set the 'msg' column to 'red' if 'A' is not an empty string

```
In [6]: df['msg'][df['A'] != ''] = 'red;'

In [7]: df
Out[7]:
   A  B  msg
0  x  x  red;
1     x
2  x     red;
3
```

Concatenate 'blue' depending on the 'B' column values

```
In [8]: df['msg'][df['B'] != ''] += 'blue;'

In [9]: df
Out[9]:
   A  B       msg
0  x  x  red;blue;
1     x     blue;
2  x         red;
3
```

Alternatively, I found using **numpy.where** produced the desired result.  What is the proper way to do this in Pandas?

```
import numpy as np

df['msg'] += np.where(df['A'] != '','green;', '')
```

**Update: 4/15/2018**

Upon further thought, it would be useful to retain the data from the original DataFrame in certain cases but still attach a label ('color' in this example).  The answer from @COLDSPEED led me to the following (changing 'blue;' to 'blue:' and preserving column 'B' data to include in the tag in this case):

```
df['msg'] = (v.where(df.applymap(len) > 0, '') + 
             df.where(df[['B']].applymap(len)>0,'')).agg(''.join, axis=1)


   A  B         msg
0  x  x  red;blue:x
1     x      blue:x
2  x           red;
3
```

Comment: Are all values in the original `df` identical? Or could they differ?

Comment: I’m not sure I follow. The columns could contain various characters or text but there are no numeric or NaN values. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I wanted to know if everything in your dataframe is `x`, but your answer is quite helpful in another sense - the dtype being string across all columns is crucial to the working of the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know your colors before-hand, you could use masking with `DataFrame.where` and `str.join` to get this done.

```
v = pd.DataFrame(
     np.repeat([['red;', 'blue;']], len(df), axis=0), 
     columns=df.columns, 
     index=df.index
) 
df['msg'] = v.where(df.applymap(len) > 0, '').agg(''.join, axis=1)
```

```
df
   A  B        msg
0  x  x  red;blue;
1     x      blue;
2  x          red;
3
```

Comment: I see where you’re going. This could be very useful. My df source is an excel sheet that I can’t modify and there are columns I need to skip but the ‘color’ list could contain an empty string for that column location.

Comment: @Robert Indeed, that is a resourceful way of handling that sort of case.

Comment: This is a great way of doing it.

Answer (score 4):

Using `pandas.DataFrame.dot`
Special note that I set the dtype of the array to `object`.  Otherwise the `dot` won't work.

```
a = np.array(['red', 'blue;'], object)

df.assign(msg=df.astype(bool).dot(a))

   A  B        msg
0  x  x  red;blue;
1     x      blue;
2  x          red;
3
```

Answer (score 4):

You can using `dot` and `replace`

```
(df!='').dot(df.columns).replace({'A':'red;','B':'blue;'},regex=True)
Out[379]: 
0    red;blue;
1        blue;
2         red;
3             
dtype: object

#df['msg']=(df!='').dot(df.columns).replace({'A':'red;','B':'blue;'},regex=True)
```